# Runtime Shared Libraries

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

What is RSL and what is the use of RSL?

Have any sample example , Please shared me,.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Runtime shared libraries**](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Flex_3:Feature_Introductions:Flex_3_RSLs)

> RSLs are just SWF files whose code is used as a shared library between different application SWF files. There are two kinds of RSLs, signed and unsigned. Signed RSLs are libraries that are signed by Adobe and may be stored in the Flash Player Cache, which can be accessed by applications from any domain. This means if your application is using a signed RSL, the RSL may not even need to be downloaded if the RSL is already in the Flash Player Cache. The signed RSL may have been put into the Flash Player Cache by visiting another web site that was using the same signed RSL. Signed RSLs have a "swz" extension.

Also read:

- [Introduction to RSL](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=rsl_02.html)
- [RSL load time savings](http://www.newtriks.com/?p=580)
- [Deploying RSLs in flex](http://quetwo.com/2009/01/22/deploying-rsls-in-flex/)

---

*The links provided in this post are taken from the first page of the Google results for the query [flex rsl](http://www.google.com/search?q=flex+rsl)*